# When I get sensor values combine with opengl in Android, It always be crash

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-sensors

I try using sensor to get raw, pitch and roll values.

But I send the value to Renderer class or GLSurfaceView class

that all will be crash when I run on my smartphone.

I tried use:

`Renderer.raw = value[0];` in MainActivity class,  or

`MainActivity.x = raw;` in Renderer class, or

use Function:

```
void setRaw(float raw){
this.raw = raw;
}
```

and call function in MainActivity.

all unluck...

this is my code:

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        glView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(glView);


        baccel = false;
        bcompass = false;

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accel = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        compass = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        glView.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
                accel,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
                compass,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        glView.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, accel);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, compass);
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                accelValues[i] = event.values[i];
            }
            baccel = true;
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                compassValues[i] = event.values[i];
            }
            bcompass = true;
            break;
        }
        if (!baccel || !bcompass)
            return;

        if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accelValues,
                compassValues)) {

            SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix,
                    SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, rotationMatrix);

            SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, values);
            update();
            baccel = false;
            bcompass = false;
        }

    }
    void update() {
        gv.setRaw(values[0]);
        gv.setPitch(values[1]);
        gv.setRoll(values[2]);
    }

}
```

and in MyGlSurfaceView:

```
float raw, pitch, roll;

protected void setRaw(float raw){
    this.raw = raw;
}
protected void setPitch(float pitch){
    this.pitch = pitch;
}
protected void setRoll(float roll){
    this.roll = roll;
}
```

[this is my log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TrRm.jpg)

Can someone help me?

My init code:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private GLSurfaceView glView;
    SensorManager mSensorManager;
    Sensor accel;
    Sensor compass;
    private MyGLSurfaceView gv;

    boolean baccel, bcompass = false;
    float[] accelValues = new float[3];
    float[] compassValues = new float[3];
    float[] rotationMatrix = new float[9];
    float[] values = new float[3];
```

MyGLSurfaceView init:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    MyGLRenderer mRenderer;


    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer(context);
        this.setRenderer(mRenderer);

        this.requestFocus();
        this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }
```

Comment: `gv` is not defined anywhere. What is it?

Comment: MyGLSurfaceView gv. I defined it at the begin.
Because the function is in MyGLSurfaceView class.
If I don't get the sensor value to other class, It's fine.
But I get the sensor value to other class, that would be crash

Comment: Well it's null so. Show us the code where you initialize it.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Change `gv` for `glView`

Comment: But if I change for glView,It tell me doesn't defineded setRaw , setPitch, setRoll function.How can I fixed it? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you know what is going on here.

When you do `private MyGLSurfaceView gv;` gv is a **null** variable. It means that if you don't do something like `gv = new ......` it will stay null for the rest of the app cycle. This means that `update()` will throw NPE.

On another hand you have `glView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);`. This suggests me that glView is a MyGLSurfaceView right? So you should define it like `private MyGLSurfaceView glView;` and not `private GLSurfaceView glView;` even if `MyGLSurfaceView` extends `GLSurfaceView`

So you should use `glView` since it's the only variable that you're actually defining and instantiating correctly. But do do this, and to use the set angles method you have to change `private GLSurfaceView glView` to `private MyGLSurfaceView glView`.

**Concluding:**

Change `private GLSurfaceView glView` to `private MyGLSurfaceView glView`

and

remove `gv` and use only `glView`

Comment: oh! I miss the step,  I have to defined a new project for it.
It's work, Thank you very much :)